# Questions about C# .NET versions and support deadlines

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I see that there are deadlines for .NET 6 support (12 November 2024). Let's assume I have an existing enterprise software with .NET 6 and C# and support ended. I'm curious what will happen if there is something wrong with .NET or with the C# language.

Another question: let's assume I started developing some software with C# and .NET and deadline passed while I was still developing. What will happen in that case? Will my C# code work in the new versions or am I stuck with the old versions? Will I have to worry about migrating my code and project?

or let's say what happens if a client doesn't have the correct version for my software on their machine?

I'm sorry if my questions are stupid but I'm confused with different versions of .NET and their support deadlines.

In my opinion, there should be a single version of .NET which should be updated as needed and it should work seamlessly with previous updates. Why there are different versions and support deadlines?

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: microsoft has been awesome documenting the ways to upgrade from one version to the next

Comment: `there should be a single version of .NET which should be updated as needed and it should work seamlessly with previous updates.` that would only work in very limited scenarios. All popular languages and platforms have breaking changes at some point and discard misused features and libraries. The only way to avoid this is to ... not be used. Should .NET Core keep supporting COM, even though that technology doesn't exist on Linux? Or should .NET ignore JSON because it didn't exist 20 years ago?

Comment: You're concerned that new versions will somehow invalidate old code but at the same time proposing that there are no new (major) versions but instead _one version_ that everyone uses, which would create the same problem you feared because those with older code they're not ready to migrate to the new, must-use-or-your-code-will-break capabilities would be...left behind?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious what will happen if there is something wrong with .NET or with the C# language.

It will get fixed. That's a very weird question, do you have an example of the problem you encountered?

> I started developing some software with C# and .NET and deadline passed while I was still developing. What will happen in that case? Will my C# code work in the new versions or am I stuck with the old versions?

Perhaps it's the word deadline that you don't understand, the end-of-support date on .Net versions is precisely to get you to upgrade to the newer .Net version instead of using an obsolete version.

> if a client doesn't have the correct version for my software on their machine?

That's your problem, .Net supports encapsulated publishing which includes all (possibly trimmed) assemblies used by your application. You don't need to install any run-time at all unless you choose to.

> In my opinion, there should be a single version of .NET which should be updated as needed and it should work seamlessly with previous updates

That's exactly what you have today, I haven't had a single issue upgrading my production software from .Net Core 3.1 all the way to .Net 7 today.